# I messed up clicked the wrong installer when updating ubuntu and can no longer use windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

All of my files are on the partition but grub no longer comes up when i turn on the computer it goes directly into ubuntu 17.10 is there anyway to fix this

Comment: Not sure if it will help but which version of Windows is it and do you know if the drive is GPT formatted or MBR?